# Функция не выводит информацию в input

Tags: javascript, html, input

HTML

```js
var ReadOut = document.getElementsByName('ReadOut');
var Currents = 0;
var FlagNewNum = false;
var PendingOp = "";

// push number

function NumPressed(Num) {
  if (FlagNewNum) {
    ReadOut.value = Num;
    FlagNewNum = false;
  } else {
    if (ReadOut.value == "0")
      ReadOut.value = Num;
    else
      ReadOut.value += Num;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block" style="cursor: move; position: absolute;">
  <script src="js/fCalc.js"></script>
  <form name="calc" action="" id="form" class="colortext" method="POST">
    <table class="tblCalc" cellpadding="0 cellspacing=0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan=5 aling="middle">
          <input id="editWide" name="ReadOut" type="text" placeholder="enter number" size=40></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="number" name="btnSeven" type="Button" value="7" onclick="NumPressed(7)"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Это кусочек формы для калькулятора.
Почему при нажатии кнопки btnSeven в поле ReadOut цифра 7 не появляется? Дебажу в мозиле, она показывает что функция NumPressed выполняется, приходит семерка, идут проверки и по идее ReadOut.value += Num; должно вывести в ReadOut "7". Но этого не происходит.

Comment: `ReadOut` — это не элемент, а список элементов, используйте `ReadOut[0]` например

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что вы пытались получить значение которого в `ReadOut` нету, т.е. `value`, `ReadOut` это список элементов, вам нужно получить `value` вот так `ReadOut[0].value`:

```js
var ReadOut = document.getElementsByName('ReadOut');
var Currents = 0;
var FlagNewNum = false;
var PendingOp = "";

// push number

function NumPressed(Num) {
    if (FlagNewNum) {
        ReadOut[0].value = Num;
        FlagNewNum = false;
    }
    else {
        if (ReadOut.value == "0")
            ReadOut[0].value = Num;
        else
            ReadOut[0].value += Num;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div id="block" style="cursor: move; position: absolute;">
        <script src="js/fCalc.js"></script>
        <form name="calc" action="" id="form" class="colortext" method="POST">
            <table class="tblCalc" cellpadding="0 cellspacing=0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=5 aling="middle">
                        <input id="editWide" name="ReadOut" type="text" placeholder="enter number" size=40></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input class="number" name="btnSeven" type="Button" value="7" onclick="NumPressed(7)"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: почему тот же код в crome не работает а в mozila работает

Comment: @Padawan, данный код был тестирован в Chrome Версия 62.0.3202.6

Comment: ясно, спасибо. Видимо у меня что то не то. Даже internet exploer отработал а crome и Яндекс.Браузер не хотят))